# Stored procedure returning query and rowcount

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Am I able to return the table query and also the rowcount? I want to return my table but i also want to notify the user if my stored procedure doesn't return anything.

This is what i have so far:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pwp_getCouponRedemption]
(
    @couponCode varchar(max)
)
AS
SELECT CouponCode, CouponValue
FROM pwpCouponCodes cc
WHERE cc.CouponCode = @couponCode
ORDER BY cc.CouponCode
```

Here is my asp code:

```
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("pwp_getCouponRedemption", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@couponCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comm.Parameters["@couponCode"].Value = couponCode;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sqlCouponCode =  reader[0].ToString();
                sqlCouponValue = float.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
            }
         } 
         blah blah catch final code...
```

I am very new to all of this so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you call this stored procedure? Do you have already written that code?

Comment: I have written that code already. It is through asp.net c#. Just doing a regular `SqlDataReader`

Comment: Could you add that code at your question?

Comment: Sure. I just added it. Please see the above

Comment: If you are only interested in the zero records case, and not in how many rows are returned otherwise, you could just keep a counter variable in your C# code. Increment it while `SqlDataReader` returns rows. If it is 0, notify the user. Come to think of it, you can use this approach to count rows returned too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this:

First change your stored procedure to be like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pwp_getCouponRedemption]
(
    @couponCode varchar(max)
)
AS

-- This is the first result returned by your SqlDataReader
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM pwpCouponCodes cc
WHERE cc.CouponCode = @couponCode
ORDER BY cc.CouponCode

-- This is the second result available if the call to NextResult() returns true
SELECT CouponCode, CouponValue
FROM pwpCouponCodes cc
WHERE cc.CouponCode = @couponCode
ORDER BY cc.CouponCode
```

Now change your calling code to be something like this

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("pwp_getCouponRedemption", conn))
{
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@couponCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    comm.Parameters["@couponCode"].Value = couponCode;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
               int countRecord = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
               if (reader.NextResult())
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                      sqlCouponCode =  reader[0].ToString();
                      sqlCouponValue = float.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                   }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error at `int countRecord = Convert.ToInt32(reader(0));` saying `'reader' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'. Any ideas what i am doing wrong. Almost using an exact copy of your code.

Comment: Sorry, mismatch between test code in VB.NET and this answer in C#, fixing now

Comment: Thank you, Please let me know when you are done making changes.

Comment: It should be complete now

Comment: Steve thank you for all of the help, but i tried putting an else on the end that would throw an error saying that nothing returned and am getting nothing back. Do you know of a reason why this would not be working?

Comment: Actually i was able to figure it out. thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your stored procedure to this:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[pwp_getCouponRedemption]
(
    @couponCode varchar(max)
)
AS
SELECT CouponCode, CouponValue, 1 AS FoundACouponForYou
FROM pwpCouponCodes cc
WHERE cc.CouponCode = @couponCode
ORDER BY cc.CouponCode;
```

Change your C# code to this:

```
    try
    {
        bool foundACouponCode = false;
        conn.Open();
        using(reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
               int countRecord = Convert.ToInt32(reader(0));
               if (reader.NextResult())
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                      sqlCouponCode =  reader[0].ToString();
                      sqlCouponValue = float.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                      foundACouponCode = reader[2].ToString() == "1";
                   }
                } 
            }
            if (!foundACouponCode)
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to find a coupon code!");
        }
    }
```

TBH you don't even need to change your stored procedure if you don't want to, you could just set the foundACouponCode to true if it passes through that piece of code as it will only get there if there was a coupon code.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to know if the stored proc is returning rows you can test on

```
var zeroRows = reader.HasRows ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just check sqlCouponCode after the end of the loop. It is only being set inside the loop.

```
if(sqlCouponCode != null)
{
    //There are no rows...do something
}
```